# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.xd.dirt.integration.rabbit.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean

Tags: ssl, spring-amqp

In our Spring application we added spring rabbit listner to read the messages. after  adding the SSL then we are getting the following error(Class not found Exception). Then added the POM dependency for spring-xd_dirt in POM file. After that its getting error like missing artifact in pom.xml. 
Could someone help me to find the dependent JAR files?

```
<bean id="clientConnectionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.xd.dirt.integration.rabbit.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean">
        <property name="useSSL" value="true" />
</bean>
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.xd</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-xd-dirt</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> 
    Multiple annotations found at this line:
        - Missing artifact org.kitesdk:kite-data-
         core:jar:0.13.0
        - Missing artifact jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.6
```

Comment: May be you mean `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean`? Fully unclear why would one use such a project out of support like Spring XD...

Comment: Thanks Artem. it worked with the one you suggested class file for me. But issue here is https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/ (RabbitConnectionFactoryBean and Configuring SSL) - the example they have mentioned the class file which I have mentioned in this issue. Could you please suggest site page owner to correct that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you mean `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitConnectionF‌​actoryBean`? Fully unclear why would one use such a project out of support like Spring XD...

> it worked with the one you suggested class file for me. But issue here is docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle (RabbitConnectionFactoryBean and Configuring SSL) - the example they have mentioned the class file which I have mentioned in this issue.

Please, raise a JIRA on the matter and we will fix it: https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP!

Comment: Thanks Artem, here is the JIRA ticket details https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-815